# vscode doesn't recognized my django module app. Warning from vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I installed some extensions in Visual Studio Code for develop in Django. My only problem is when I'm trying to do this;

[Opening folder in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlmLw.png)

[import views from my_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwpOO.png)

[Complete view of the explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntyfj.png)

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5C9u.png)

from **my_app_name** import views

I received a warning from Visual Studio Code.

If a typed like this;

from **.** import views

I don't received any warning! But a would prefer the other form above.

1. I have python 3.x installed on my laptop.
2. I have Anaconda environment created.
3. I have some extensions installed (Python, Django, Pylint,...)

Note: My project run well because is only a warning but I would prefer that warning disappear.

**Fast solution for me:**

[open project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwhvX.png)
Just open one project directory.

Comment: It's unclear what project structure you have, if your path is not root of project that won't work. Here is good article about imports https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be several issues here (If the Warning appears only in the problems panel, I believe you should start with the last one)

To rule them out try this:

## Django related:

create a new project and add a module

`django-admin startproject your_project`

`python manage.py startapp your_app`

---

## Visual Studio Code related:

Chose the interpreter+linter(pylint) from your conda environment [vs-code-interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter)

---

## Visual Studio Code / Django related:

Add this to your workspace settings

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
```

[vs code linting in django](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_commandline-arguments-and-configuration-files)
Therefore you need this plugin:[pylint-django](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation! The thing is that I am taking a course of Django in Udemy and the teacher do his practices in Atom. Somebody told me about Visual Studio Code and I'm very surprise of so fast is it. I opened a general directory that have all my projects of Django made in Atom. Then I realize if I only open one project directory the problem is solved.
And in this part that you talk about:
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"]
I have this part empty.
 "python.linting.pylintArgs": [ ]

Comment: For me: "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"] made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the Error that `django-not-configured (E5110): *Django was not configured`, you also need to run `pylint --django-settings-module=<YOUR DJANGO PROJECT NAME>.settings` or add it to your `settings.json` file of your Django project. I prefer the latter and therefore my `settings.json` has these entries:

```
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins","pylint_django",
        "--django-settings-module","<YOUR DJANGO PROJECT NAME>.settings",
    ],
```

**NOTE:** The `<YOUR DJANGO PROJECT NAME>` should be replaced by the *name of your Django project*.